# android ble onCharactersticChanged stop notified after sometime

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my android app. we have two different characteristics for writing and listen changes of gatt server. Every thing is working well like periodically i am getting data on onCharactersticChanged as well as i am also able to write data to gatt server. but after sometime onCharactersticChanged stop getting called and after that i am also not able to write anything on gatt server. after disconnect and reconnect it start working again. is anyone face such issue with android BLE. not getting such issue with iPhone

Comment: Do you get the same problem when using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Yes same i am facing with NRF also

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility of bugs in the GATT server device? You could check the Android hci log or use an air sniffer to see what's really going on.